# Можно ли получить доступ к пропсам child при итерации по Children.toArray(children) React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Всем привет. Я пытаюсь сделать компонент, в котором хотелось бы проитерироваться по массиву потомков(1) и использовать их в другом компоненте(2) + использовать один из пропсов дочернего(1) компонента для его(2) настройки. При этом в консоли показываеся объект с нужными мне пропсами.

Выглядит это примерно так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Пройти `map`'ом по массиву `children`:

```
export const MultiInput = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {children.map((child) => (
        <FormItem name={child.props.name}>{child}</FormItem>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: В таком случае мне выдает ошибку typescript: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'boolean | ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal'

Comment: В `MultiInputProps` для `children` нужно указать тип - массив элементов, например `children: JSX.Element[]`